# eAccelerator ignore my new setting?

Tags: php

Im using eAccelerator 0.9.5.2, CentOS 5.3, lighttpd 1.4.22

But because eAccelerator is cached in RAM, I needs too much RAM. So Im trying to cache in hard disk.
(my website is not generate money, so Im thinking about cheaper solution)

So, I modify `/etc/php.d/eaccelerator.ini` with below codes:
`extension="eaccelerator.so"

eaccelerator.shm_size="12"

eaccelerator.cache_dir="/var/cache/eaccelerator"

eaccelerator.enable="1"

eaccelerator.optimizer="1"

eaccelerator.check_mtime="0"

eaccelerator.debug="0"

eaccelerator.filter=""

eaccelerator.shm_max="20M"

eaccelerator.shm_ttl="1800"

eaccelerator.shm_prune_period="0"

eaccelerator.shm_only="0"

eaccelerator.compress="0"

eaccelerator.compress_level="9"

eaccelerator.keys="disk_only"

eaccelerator.sessions="disk_only"

eaccelerator.content="disk_only"`

So, the output of phpinfo() as below:
http://img175.imageshack.us/img175/1104/screenshggot.png

But after using "disk_only" in eAccelerator and restart lighttpd & php-cgi using `killall`, my RAM usage is still high for php-cgi. Reboot the server also not works.

The data is created in cache directory, but RAM usage is still high.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `eaccelerator.shm_size="12"` with `eaccelerator.disk_size="12"`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your cache_dir (/var/cache/eaccelerator) exists and is writable by everyone. Usually it's in the temp (/tmp) directory.

Comment: I think that you do NOT want it to be writable by everyone.  That's a security hole because that code gets executed, and you're letting anyone write to the files that are getting executed.